# How to write a single file per partition with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a bunch of files with timeseries data from some IoT sensors. I need to aggregate data per hour per IoT device and partition the resulting files per day. Currently there is not much data and not many devices so I can handle it locally with a single laptop.

I've managed to get a single file per day instead of a file per device per day using `repartition(1)`. But as far as I understand this is inefficient as this basically moves all the data to a single node to do all the processing. I've read that handling partitions becomes really important in order to improve performance but it seems quite low level and requires knowledge about the size of your data.

So I was wondering, is there any strategy to handle repartitioning of the data? In my case, I need a single file to improve efficiency when loading the resulting parquet files (using AWS Athena) as aggregations per hour partitioned by day for a bunch of devices results on just a few lines to read per file. Maybe I need to aggregate the files in a second step?

This is the code I currently use to test the aggregation of the data.

```
df
      .drop("name")
      .filter(!_.anyNull)
      .withColumn("timestamp_seconds", from_unixtime(col("time").divide(1000000000)).cast("timestamp")) //Timestamp in nanoseconds
      .withColumn("day", to_date(col("timestamp_seconds")))
      .withColumn("hour", hour(col("timestamp_seconds")))
      .drop("timestamp_seconds")
      .groupBy("id", "day","hour").agg(avg("soc").as("avg_soc"))
      .where("avg_soc != 0")
      .orderBy("id", "day", "hour")
      .repartition(1)
      .write
      .partitionBy("day")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .csv("data/aggregate") //I'm using CSV for now in order to see the data
```

Comment: maybe `.repartition("day")` instead of 1?

Comment: @mck thanks! That did the trick. I feel a bit like an idiot now. While searching for an answer, all the examples I saw used a number to repartition the data but I never thought of checking the API to see whether the method accepted other type of parameters.

Comment: that's a new feature... you might have been looking at some old answers

Comment: Just in case someone else checks this answer, the actual syntax is `repartition(col("day"))` as it takes `Column` as the type.